# using multiple timer in an activity

Tags: android, timer

i'm trying to use two timer in an activity,i have an imagview who i need to setivisible after 200 ml and after 4000ml new intent starts,my code is this:

```
   public class welcome extends Activity {
   @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
    Timer timer=new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ImageView img1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_img1);
            img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    },200);
  Timer timer1=new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
            Intent intent=new Intent(welcome.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    },4000);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

thanks for your helps

Comment: use `Handler`, so they will be called on UI thread

Comment: Timers don't measure time in milliliters... ;)

Comment: We have this in timer  timer = new CountDownTimer(4000, 200) where the second value represent onTick event to be occur after specified time ie. 200 here

Answer (score 1):

Try this way: using `Runnable` and `Handler`

```
 Runnable r2=new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ImageView img1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_img1);
                    img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            };

            Handler h2=new Handler();
            h2.postDelayed(r2,200);
```

and

```
    Runnable r3=new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        finish();
                        Intent intent=new Intent(welcome.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                };

                Handler h3=new Handler();
                h3.postDelayed(r3,4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use countdown timer

```
CountDownTimer timer;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    timer.start();
    timer = new CountDownTimer(4000, 200) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        ImageView img1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_img1);
        img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            finish();
        Intent intent=new Intent(welcome.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

}

Hope this helps.